# Unexpected identifier in JQuery while working perfect in HTML

Tags: jquery, variables

I seem to have an "Unexpected identifier" in my JQuery script, but I cannot find where...

```
var click = "window.open(
            'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)',
            'facebook-share-dialog',
            'width=626,height=436');
        return false;";
var facebookshare = '<a href="#" onclick="' + click + '"><img src="http://w.sharethis.com/images/facebook_counter.png" /></a>';
$('<div class="facebook">' + facebookshare + '</div>').insertAfter('.easy_social-widget-twitter');
```

When I use the same code in pure HTML, is does the trick... Why not in this JQuery script?

Other cases on StackOverflow indicates an unclosed function (or something else), but that's not the case. Because I replace this snippet with `alert("check");` I get the proper alert!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it could have been solved by any syntax coloring editor

Comment: Strings are not multiline -> http://jsfiddle.net/UbgQn/

Comment: +1 for multiline! Please add it as an answer!

Answer (score 2):

You miss the `\` to make a multi-line string literal and you have a quote that shouldn't be there.

Change your `click` string declaration to

```
var click = "window.open(\
            'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)',\
            'facebook-share-dialog',\
            'width=626,height=436');\
        return false;";
```

But you shouldn't inline code like this, you're only looking for problems. Use jQuery's `on` function to set the event handler. You should never generate JS code in JS (well, almost never, but take it as "never" until you're experienced enough).

Comment: I already tried that, but no luck there...

Comment: Thanks for the great tip on the `on` function!